# The number of simultaneous report jobs was limited to 160 by the system administrator. . Please try to reconnect later. [RCIRAS0542]

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

When i try to view the crystal report in infoView, it is throwing exception as

The number of simultaneous report jobs was limited to 160 by the system administrator. . Please try to reconnect later. [RCIRAS0542]

I restarted all servers, it is not resolved. Will any one help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i increased Max. Concurrent Jobs value field for the Crystal report Processing Server 
then the issue is resolved.